# Getting "Use of uninitialized value within array in join or string" error in spite of creating new variable using 'my' in each iteration

Tags: perl, file-io

I have two set of files (say set 1 and set 2). I have to read corresponding files from both sets and output corresponding file (with a modified name).

Code looks like this:

```
my @files = <path/to/directory/containing/both/set/of/files/*>;

foreach my $file (@files) {  # pick a file from directory

  my $str;
  my $lines;
  my @arr;
  my @ans;                                      # need new version of these for every file

  open(FH, $file) or die "Can't open file $!" ; # open file from set1 and copy everything to single string
  $lines = do { local $/; <FH> };

  open(MYFILE, ">tagged$basename.xml");         # open flle to be written into

  # basename extracted correctly, open corresponding file from set2
  open(FILE, "<outtrain$basename");
  while (<FILE>) {

    # code modifying $lines and output stored in @ans, works perfectly for single file
    my $k   = 0;
    my $num = 0;    # no.(yr/vol/pg etc.)  to be searched and tagged in xml file

    # find tag and num (see outtrain file, 1st no. is tag
    if (/(\d)\sdummy\,(\d*\.*\d*)\,(\d*\.*\d*)/) {
      $num = $3 * 1000;
      $tag = $1;
    }

    # important variables: @ans would store final (tagged) output array, @flag helps in
    # shifting charaters to right so that tags can be inserted (shifted version of @arr is
    # @ans, and after all shiftings have been done, @ans would store final tagged array.
    # @index is the position around which tags are to be inserted, $check ensures only 1st
    # matching of $num in @lines is considered

    my $check = 0;
    $flag = 0;
    for ($k = $index + $flag ; $k <= $#arr ; $k++) {
      $ans[$k + $flag] = $arr[$k];
      if (($arr[$k] eq $num) && ($check eq 0)) {
        $flag  = 2;
        $index = $k;
        $check = 1;
      }
    }

    # after arrays is shifted, time to insert the tags around ($index+1) in @ans
    if ($tag eq 4) {
      $ans[$index]     = '<Volume>';
      $ans[$index + 1] = $num;
      $ans[$index + 2] = '</Volume>';
    }
    if ($tag eq 1) {
      $ans[$index]     = '<Year>';
      $ans[$index + 1] = $num;
      $ans[$index + 2] = '</Year>';
    }
    if ($tag eq 2) {
      $ans[$index]     = '<StartPg>';
      $ans[$index + 1] = $num;
      $ans[$index + 2] = '</StartPg>';
    }
    if ($tag eq 3) {
      $ans[$index]     = '<EndPg>';
      $ans[$index + 1] = $num;
      $ans[$index + 2] = '</EndPg>';
    }

    #@arr=();
    @arr = @ans;

    #print "\n@arr";
  }

  $str = join(" ", @ans); # (line 56) # $str to be printed to outputfile
  print MYFILE "$str";    # print to file

  $lines = ();                # clear $lines, though I think it's useless

  close(MYFILE);
  close(FILE);
  close(FH);
}
```

It works perfectly for single file, but when I try to iterate, I get the error

```
Use of uninitialized value within @ans in join or string at tagger.pl line 56, <FILE> line 97.
```

I also tried making all these variables global, but then I started getting same output (output from 1st file being read) in every file.

Comment: Did you make a `Dumper\@ans`?

Comment: The problem lies in the code you are not showing, where you store in `@ans`. You should always say which line your error points to, so that people reading your question do not have to guess.

Comment: As I said, it works fine if I have a single file and no foreach loop to iterate over all files in the directory (Yes, I'm making sure correct files are being read). Then, @ans comes out of loop as expected. When I try to iterate, I face problems.

Comment: No, it is not working fine, as you clearly are getting an error when you try to use the values in `@ans`. You need to show the code that assigns values to `@ans`, or this error is impossible to fix.

Comment: That is quite messy code you have there. At a guess, you are using direct assignment and skipping over one or more indexes, i.e. `$ans[0] = "foo"; $ans[2] = "bar";` (so `$ans[1]` is left undefined).

Comment: Instead of using direct assignment to an index, you could try using the array manipulating functions, i.e. `push @ans, "<Volume>", $num, "</Volume>"`. That way you do not need to keep track of `$index`, it always adds to the end of the array, without risk of inserting empty indexes.

Comment: You should also know that it is not necessary to join an array before printing it. You can just do `print @ans`, since `print` takes a list of arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll look into them. Join is important because I have to do some regex operations before printing to file.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, it might be easier for us to help you if you just provide example data and what you want the result to be -- but TLP is certainly correct, you haven't initailized one of the @ans elements.

Comment: Presumably this isn't the code that is causing the problem as you don't define `$basename`, which should presumably be derived from `$file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such limited information, the best way I can help you is to show how your `while` loop could be coded.

Note these points

- There is the bare minimum of comments. If your code needs a lot of comments to make it comprehensible then you should write it more intelligibly and choose better identifiers
- It uses `autodie` so that you don't have to code explicit tests for the status of each `open` call (which you do for only one of the three `open`s in any case
- It uses *lexical file handles* and the *three-parameter form* of `open`, which is current best practice
- All variables are declared as *late* as possible; usually at the point they are defined
- I have rewritten the regex pattern to what I think you mean, and used the `/x` modifier so that I could space it out to make it more readable. In your original code *everything* was optional in the second and third captures
- It skips a line from the *outtrain* file altogether if it doesn't match the regex. Your code simply avoids assigning `$num` and `$tag` in case of a mismatch, but continues to use their values regardless
- There is a global array that defines the correspondency between numbers and tag names, avoiding the need for multiple `if` statements
- `@arr` is modified *in place*, by using double-quote interpolation to wrap it in the appropriate start and end tags

You don't show how `@arr` is populated so I have left its declaration commented. You also don't show any data so I have had to make several guesses, but you should get more mileage with this code than what you started with.

It *does* compile as it stands, but you will have to weave it into the rest of your existing code. But I haven't been able to test it in the absence of useable data

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Basename 'basename';

my @tags = qw/ none Year StartPg EndPg Volume /;

my @files = <path/to/directory/containing/both/set/of/files/*>;

for my $file (@files) {

  my $basename = basename $file;
  my @arr = ();                # How does this get filled?

  my $lines = do {             # What is this for? Perhaps @arr = split /\n/, $lines?
    open my $fh, '<', $file;   
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
  };

  open my $tagged_fh,   '>', "tagged$basename.xml";
  open my $outtrain_fh, '<', "outtrain$basename";

  while (<$outtrain_fh>) {

    next unless / (\d) \s+ dummy , (\d+(?:\.\d*)?) , (\d+(?:\.\d*)?) /x;

    my $num = $3 * 1000;
    my $tag = $tags[$1];

    for my $item (@arr) {
      $item = qq{<$tag>$item</$tag>} if $item == $num;
    }
  }

  print $tagged_fh @arr;
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Some minor errors still remain, but I've got them.